# Request to alter order of "All Sites" in drop down list

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange-button

While I understand the requirement of 200 points on a site to have it listed on your flair, I would much appreciate if the minimum for sites to be listed to be changed to 100 (if that) in the "all sites" drop down of the StackExchange menu at the top left.

Supporting factors:

1. It's not flair, it holds no bragging rights.  It's simply ease of use.  There's no need to be picky on the minimum
2. This will ensure that sites I've joined (after getting the 100 point bonus) will be listed.  The likely hood of me participating on a site is much higher if I've bothered to join it, thus having it readily available benefits me.
3. I assume some thought was put in to randomize the list in order to expose people new sites/ones they have not considered visiting.  This will still be accomplished through the banner ads on top and on the right column
4. "*Oh this guy is just new and wants everything his way*" - While my measly 1k on SO doesn't compare many of the veterans and experts, I consider myself and involved and dedicated user (I own an SO coffee mug if that helps...) and would appreciate a feature that makes things easier for me
5. "*Just be patient.  Eventually you'll have enough points where this wont be an issue for you*" - Perhaps.  However I not as well versed in that many areas, and have joined other sites simply for learning purposes and the occasional comment (a point-less interaction).  While I intend to expand my programming languages and other various SE related activities, I know I'll be on the low end for a while.
6. Why have a minimum anyway?  Why not list all sites in order of most involved?  It just makes sense

Comment: When I look at the "all sites" drop down, I see *all* of the sites, even ones on which I have no account.

Comment: Makes sense seeing how it is a button that says "all sites."  Good thing this question is about the order in which they appear.

Comment: I see. That was completely unclear to me from your question.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to see all your accounts just go to [the accounts tab of your profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/167022/stevether?tab=accounts).

Comment: Why navigate two pages away when it could be much simpler?

Comment: @stevether Why not link to everything from everything? :P

Comment: I already have that! They're all there, I just don't like having to scroll through a randomized list every time.  I like structure, it would be nice if they were formated.